# Push Notifications and Services for iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, multitasking

I have an app which is tracking the coordinates of the user. I want the user to receive a push notification at a specific longitude and latitude. That means that my device has to track coordinates and make requests even if it's closed.
Is there any way to accomplish this? 
Push Notifications can't do this.

Comment: quickblox.com - maybe it what you needs

Answer (score 1):

CLLocationManager actually has a method, `startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy:` to monitor for when a users enters a region and wake your app if needed. See more [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10). I'm pretty sure this is the system they use for their Reminders app, where you can get a reminder at a specific location. It uses a lot less energy than having your app monitor the location all the time, since the OS can use information like which cell towers or wifi hotspots you are nearby, to figure out if it's even necessary to use the GPS.

Comment: Is there anyway to implement this on appcelerator?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware, no. My guess is that Apple only made this "wake me if something changes" feature for locations, since they can use the fact that the telephony hardware is always powered on. The accelerometer hardware isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3) and [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-location/)

Your app will keep running in the background and receive location updates.Then send local notification to the user. But if the user killed your app manually.The work will not been done.